# How can I calculate number of hops to reach destination ( NS2 )?

Tags: tcl, wireless, ns2

In NS2 ..in TCL file, how can I calculate number of Hops in one path to reach the destination in wireless Network?

I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

You must do that in the protocol's codes...
First of all i don't know which protocol you want to use, but fortunately the protocols in ns2 are very similar to each other... So i will c guide you to how to do it.

I will use AODV protocol as a sample...
In theory :

We'll say when a RREQ packet has arrived, increment the packet hop count for current rout...

---

This is the simplest way :

Now open `aodv.cc` For example `/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/aodv/aodv.cc` and in the lines that says :

```
// First check if I am the destination ..

if (rq->rq_dst == index) {
```

Click Enter after `if (rq->rq_dst == index) {` and write :

```
printf("Hop_Count_ %d | Packet with uid %d | from %d to %d ",rq->rq->rq_hop_count,ch->uid,ih->saddr(),ih->daddr());
```

This Code will print the hop count for each packet that **arrived** to the destination.

In terminal `cd` into your ns2 directory and type `make` and click Enter.
For example :

```
$ cd /ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
$ make
```

---

---

This is the hardest way :
In code :

Open `aodv_packet.h` from your ns2 directory... For example `/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/aodv/aodv_packet.h`

Find `struct hdr_aodv_request {` and create an interget variable in it called `hop_count_`...

Like : `struct hdr_aodv_request {
            int hop_count_;`

Now open `aodv.cc` from `/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/aodv/aodv.cc` and find the definition of `sendRequest(Packet *p)` function that might look like `void AODV::sendRequest(nsaddr_t dst) {`...

Now in this function you must see some codes like :

```
// Fill up some more fields.
rq->rq_type = AODVTYPE_RREQ;
rq->rq_hop_count = 1;
rq->rq_bcast_id = bid++;
rq->rq_dst = dst;
rq->rq_dst_seqno = (rt ? rt->rt_seqno : 0);
rq->rq_src = index;
seqno += 2;
assert((seqno % 2) == 0);
rq->rq_src_seqno = seqno;
rq->rq_timestamp = CURRENT_TIME;
```

And where it says `rq->rq_timestamp = CURRENT_TIME;` just click Enter and write the blow code :

```
rq->hop_count_ = 0;
```

Now you need to find the definition of `recvRequest(Packet *p)` that might look like `void AODV::recvRequest(Packet *p) {`...

In this function find the lines that says :

```
/*
 * Can't reply. So forward the  Route Request
 */
else {
```

After `else {` click Enter and write :

```
rq->hop_count_++;
```

In terminal `cd` into your ns2 directory and type `make` and click Enter.
For example :

```
$ cd /ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
$ make
```

Now for printing you can use the first solution that i wrote above.

---

Comment: Thank you soo much. I would like to ask you also if you have an idea how to calculate Round Trip Time (RTT) in NS2 ?? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is easy as well... You can use `NOW` variable in your protocol, and as you should already know, `NOW` variable contains the current time in simulation and it's a Decimal value... To use it for what you said, simply create a variable of type `double` in your `packet.h` in the `struct hdr_cmn{` and give it a name, for example `double ping;` and Now when you send your packet, for example in the `sendReply` you can write `ch->ping = NOW;` and when your packet get to the destination and be received you can calculate the elapsed time.. because now you have the prev time  and you have the `NOW`.

Comment: Dear Jenova,
Thank you for your replies and support.
Regarding to hop-count calculation, I'm trying to implement the first solution (Simple one) and the Make was successful. But I have a question there: When I use the fprintf , it gives error. But when I use printf , I can't find output on the terminal. Where can I find the print output from AODV.cc ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have 2 choices...First you can change the history of your terminal to `unlimited` by opening the `Profile Preferences` from `Edit` and go to the `Scrolling` tab and set the `Unlimited` to checked... you can also change the number. The second choice is that you can use the `std::ofsteam` to print something into a file... You can learn how to do that in [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) link.

Comment: Dear Jenova,

Thank you so much for helping me as I'm a beginner in NS2. Regarding to how can I calculate the Round Trip Time , can you give me more explanation because I don't find struct hdr_cmn{ in aodv_packet.h . 
Waiting for your reply Jenova.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `struct hdr_cmn{` is in `common/packet.h`... i have some work to do and they're important so i will write a long answer again and help you but for now just know that `struct hdr_cmn{` is in `common/packet.h`... i'll answer when my works are done... have a good day.

Comment: Thank you so much Jenova..wish u the same..
Waiting for your answer.

Comment: Dear Jenova,
Could you please help me to find RTT ..Thanks soo much.