# how to Identify shortest path routing in ns2

Tags: algorithm, networking, sensors, ns2

i am trying to get the shortest path between two nodes in network simulator 2 NS2, if there any function of method that i can get number of hops please?

Comment: Search https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+get+number+of+hops ... the first hit is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709673/how-can-i-calculate-number-of-hops-to-reach-destination-ns2 ... Shortest path: 
By default NS2 uses Dijkstra´s shortest path algorithm

Comment: this code exist in routing protocole AODV, and  i don't know how to add this function in my code to get the number of hops between two nodes